# How to render checkbox in ASP.Net MVC 4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a view like

FYI, checkbox input is inside foreach, when I try to use like 
`<%Html.CheckboxFor(m => m.Item.Chk)` 
it gives me an error so I used the following code.

```
<input type ="checkbox" id="chk" <% if (Item.Chk != null)%>
                    <% { %>
                        <%= Item.Chk.Value ? "checked" : String.Empty %>
                    <% } %> onclick = "updateChk(<%= Item.ID %>, <%= Item.CartID %>, this.Value);"/>
```

If I change the value in the checkbox it is passing `"on"` always whether it is checked or unchecked on `this.Value`.

How do I change value in checkbox and render in View?

Comment: Based on your code samples I would guess you would need <%Html.CheckboxFor(m => m.Item.Chk.Value) to get CheckBoxFor to work, since it looks like that is your boolean property.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried that option too but couldn't help. I didn't see my properties.